# Как запустить трейлер на странице?

Tags: iframe, видео

есть карточка фильма, каким образом можно поставить что бы трейлер загружался в браузере а не переходил на ютуб?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте любое видео на ютубе, нажмите "Поделиться" и в списке "Отправить ссылку" выберите встроить. Ютуб выдаст вам полность настроенный iframe для вопросизведение ролика на вашей странице. Вот пример:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/218EKEiuyD8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```